# Why does this hashtable function show a compilation error?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    unordered_map<string,string> myhash;
    int i,n,m,len1,len2;
    cin>>n>>m;
    string arr2[3010];
    string s1,s2;
    for ( i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        cin>>s1>>s2;
        myhash.emplace(s1,s2);
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        cin>>arr2[i];
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        len1 = arr2[i].length();
        len2 = myhash[arr2[i]].length();
        if ( len1 > len2 )
            cout<<myhash[arr2[i]]<<"\t";
        else
            cout<<arr2[i]<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

On compilation, it shows an error.

```
error: no member named 'emplace' in
      'std::__1::unordered_map<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::basic_string<char>,
      std::__1::hash<std::__1::basic_string<char> >,
      std::__1::equal_to<std::__1::basic_string<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const
      std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::basic_string<char> > > >'
                myhash.emplace(s1,s2);
```

I made the above code in which I am taking input a number of strings and adding them to the hashtable named myhash. 
Why do I see this error? Is it because my compiler doesn't support emplace function?

Comment: It compiled successfully for me without error

Comment: Are you using compiler option `-std=c++11 ` ?

Comment: It builds fine on an antiquated g++.

Comment: @Steephen if he would have forgotten that, it would have complained that there's no such thing as ``unordered_map``, no?

Comment: I used normal `make` command using terminal on my Mac.

Comment: @AmiTavory it should, you are right, checking possibilities!!

Comment: Same error here, using clang++ under OSX

Comment: But -std=c++11 fixes it, as suggested by @Steephen

Comment: @Elliot so you are using clang? or g++? What's your make file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a compiler bug - the compiler you use simply has incomplete C++11 support. For instance, gcc didn't support `emplace()` until [4.8.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44436). Your code is perfectly fine, and it compiles on a [later version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebb63e01aab7a0fe) of gcc.

Your choices are simply to make do without `emplace()` or to upgrade your compiler.